# Proving the supremum of uniform norms is 1 in a particular continuous funciton vector space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let 
$$X=C_{\Bbb R}([0,1])=\{x:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\;\; |\;x \text{  is continuous}\}$$
be a vector space over $\Bbb R$ with $\|x\|_X=\|x\|_{[0,1]}=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}{|x(t)|}$. 
 
Let 
$$M=\Big\{x\in X:\int_0^{1/2}x(t)dt-\int_{1/2}^1 x(t) dt=0\Big\}$$
I want to prove that there's not possible to find any $x_*\in M$ s.t. $\|x_*\|_{[0,1]}=\sup_{x\in M}{\|x\|_{[0,1]}}$.
I've already proved that $M$ is convex and closed ($\|\;\|_{[0,1]}$). Next, I want to show that $\sup_{x\in M}{\|x\|_{[0,1]}}=1$, but got stucked.
I've only managed to get that: 
$$\forall x\in M\;\;2\int_0^{1/2}x(t)dt=\int_0^1x(t)dt\le\|x\|_{[0,1]}$$
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: In the definition of your set $M$ is the second integral taken over $[1/2,2]$ or should it be $[1/2,1]$ perhaps?

Comment: Oh yes, miss that, thank you. Will edit that.

Comment: What about constant functions, say $x(t) = 1/3$? $\Vert x \Vert_X = 1/3 < 1$.

Comment: But I need to show that $\|x\|_X\ge 1\;\;\forall\;x\in M$ so that 
$$\inf_{x\in M}{\|x\|_X}\ge 1$$

Comment: Are you not in fact looking for the $\sup$? As the $0$ function is an element of $M$ and $\|0\|=0<1$ which shows that your required to prove statement is false.

Comment: As been told, $x_* \equiv 0 \in M$ and $\Vert 0 \Vert_X = 0$. So we have an $x \in M$ such that $\Vert x_* \Vert_X = \inf_{x \in M} \Vert x \Vert_X$. So  your statement is false.

Comment: Yes, my statement is false. Sorry about that, its the sup. Will edit it